# Get the number of rows in groupby-ed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the number of rows(elements?) of groupby-ed dataframe. Image will make it easier to explain.
Here's my dataframe `winningPap_group`. It is groupby-ed with `Paper ID`
[This is dataframe: `winningPap_group`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m3ha.png)

Here what I need to do is get the number of Laureate ID in each paper ID group. For example the number of Laureate ID in Paper ID==1.147687e+07 is 3. I would like to know how should I code to make it happen.

Comment: use `winningPap_group.groupby('Paper ID')['Paper ID'].size()` or  `winningPap_group.groupby('Paper ID')['Paper ID'].transform('size')`

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! Thank you @ansev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
winningPap_group.groupby('Paper ID')['Paper ID'].size()
```

or

```
winningPap_group.groupby('Paper ID')['Paper ID'].transform('size')
```